# Python34\Scripts folder configuration after installation

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, easy-install

In the attempt to get Easy_Install working with Python34 and Python27 I've exhausted the options listed in the documentation.

Is there a way to add the Python\34\Scripts folder so I stop getting the following error?

```
>>> easy_install numpy
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    easy_install numpy
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

AND

```
>>> easy_install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'easy_install' is not defined
>>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running shell commands from the Python REPL, not from the Windows command line. Quit the REPL by typing `quit()`, `exit()`, or hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>. Open a Windows command prompt by hitting <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, typing `cmd`, and hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>. `easy_install` should now work, although for most use cases (unless you're installing from an egg), `pip` should be sufficient. It is already installed with Python 3.4 and 2.7.9, and can otherwise be installed by googling `install pip` and following the first link. `pip install numpy` is definitely the preferred way to go, as `pip` supports wheels, which more and more packages (including `numpy`) are uploading to PyPI.

Alternatively, search [Christoph Gohlke's Python Extension Packages for Windows](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) Repository for the package you're looking for. The version of `numpy` there comes statically linked to Intel's high-performance MKL library, as do a number of `numpy`-dependent packages like `scipy` and `matplotlib`. Simply download the appropriate `.whl` files from Gohlke's site, run `pip install package_name_version_whatever.whl`, and you're good to go.